# Calculate limit of $f_n(x)$ for $x \in (0, 1]$

Tags: calculus, limits

I want to calculate the limit as $n \longrightarrow \infty$ of
$$f_n(x)=-\frac{1}{x\ln n+1} + \frac{nx}{(n\ln n)x^2+1}$$
when $x \in (0, 1]$ (in fact I want to prove that it is $0$).
I am having trouble distinguishing the various possible values of $x$. For example, if $x$ is very close to $0$, then
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} f_n(x)=-\frac{1}{x\ln n+1} = -1$$
But if it is very close to $1$ then
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} f_n(x)=-\frac{1}{x\ln n+1} = 0$$
The other limit is even more problematic, because it diverges if $x$ is very close to $0$. I don't know how to manage this and, even more, I am very far from proving that the whole limit is actually $0$

Comment: Your first computation is wrong. Do not forget that, regardless how close to $0$, $x$ is a fixed number when you consider the (pointwise) limit with respect to $n$.

Comment: @alphaomega Check this out (you'll have to copy the whole link by yourself, the hyperlink is not working properly): https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+-1%2F%280.00000000000000001*logn%2B1%29+as+n-%3Einfinity

Comment: what am I looking at?

Comment: @alphaomega if you are copying the FULL link, it's the limit when $x$ is very close to $0$

Comment: fix an $x \gneqq 0$. what's the limit of $x\cdot \log n$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping in mind that $x$ is held constant as $n\to\infty$, we see that

For the first term, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{-1}{x\ln{n}+1}=0$ as $\ln{n}\to\infty$

For the second term, since both $nx$ and $(n\ln{n})x^2+1$ both tend to $\infty$, we may apply L'Hospital's Rule.

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{nx}{(n\ln{n})x^2+1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x}{(\ln{n}+1)x^2}=0$

We now conclude that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{-1}{x\ln{n}+1}+\frac{nx}{(n\ln{n})x^2+1}=0$